# How would I go about centering the middle text of a flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I have this:

HTML:

```
  </div class="container">
    <footer>Maximilian Crosby ©</footer>
  </div>
  <div class="bot-bar" >
    <a href="./contact-us.html">Contact us</a>
    <a href="./contact-us.html">Privacy</a>
    <a href="./contact-us.html">Legal</a>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container  {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 200px 10fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header"
    "advert"
    "main"
    "footer";
  text-align: center;
}

footer  {
  grid-area: footer;
  margin: 1em 0 0 0;
}

.bot-bar  {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
}
```

The problem is that the text in the footer is central but the word "Privacy" in the flex bar below is not directly below the footer text. It's off to the right a little because obviously flex is centralizing the three flex items in the flex container.

How would I go about centering the word privacy using flex?
Would I have to justify-content: center; JUST privacy and then add padding?

Answer (score 4):

Edit: Actually to keep good practices, you should add class to `a` element.

```css
.container  {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 200px 10fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header"
    "advert"
    "main"
    "footer";
  text-align: center;
}

footer  {
  grid-area: footer;
  margin: 1em 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.bot-bar  {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
}

.bot-bar__link{
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
 </div class="container">
    <footer>Maximilian Crosby ©</footer>
  </div>
  <div class="bot-bar" >
    <a class="bot-bar__link" href="./contact-us.html">Contact us</a>
    <a class="bot-bar__link" href="./contact-us.html">Privacy</a>
    <a class="bot-bar__link" href="./contact-us.html">Legal</a>
  </div>
```